# Structure pointer assignment not assigning expected value - Linked Lists

Tags: c, list, reference, reverse, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program to reverse a linked list in C. While debugging code in gdb, after the second iteration of while loop, function,`reverse`, take exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert (int number);
void print ();


struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
} head, *last_node;

int count (struct Node *);
void reverse (struct Node *);

int main () {
    int number, choice = 0;

    while (choice != 4) {
        printf ("\nChoose the action: ");
        printf ("\n 1. Insert ");
        printf ("\n 2. Print List ");
        printf ("\n 3. Reverse");
        printf ("\n 4. Exit \n");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {

            case 1 : printf ("\nEnter number to be inserted: ");
            scanf ("%d", &number);
            insert (number);
            break;

            case 2 : printf ("\nHere is/are linked list element/s: ");
            print();
            break;

            case 3 : printf ("\nLinked List Reversed ");
            reverse(&head);
            break;

            case 4 : 
            default: exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void insert (int number) {
    if (head.data == 0) {
        head.data = number;
        head.link = NULL;
        last_node = &head;
    } else {
        struct Node *new_node;
        new_node = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
        new_node -> data = number;
        new_node -> link = NULL;
        last_node -> link = new_node;
        last_node = new_node;
    }
}

void print () {
    struct Node *start;
    start = &head;
    do {
        printf ("%d ", start->data);
        start = start->link;
    } while (start != NULL);
    printf ("\n");
}


void reverse (struct Node *start) {
    struct Node *temp1 = NULL, *temp2;

    while (start->link != NULL) {
        temp2 = start->link;
        start->link = temp1;
        temp1 = start;
        start = temp2;
    } 
}
```

After running `reverse` function only first element of linked list shows.

Comment: what if `start` passed as `NULL` ? Obvious crash. _start is assigned a NULL value instead of temp2.  ?_ firstly I don't see `start` initialized with `temp2` initially &  `temp2` initially contains some intermediate data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. The problem might already be in the code that creates the list or in the way you call `reverse`.

Comment: in first iteration `temp2` is assigned with `start->link` in first line of while loop, then in fourth line `start` is assigned with `temp2`. Why `start` contain `NULL` after fourth line.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: i'm directly calling this function with `reverse(&head)`

Comment: @Jaat don't describe your code but show it. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: Another thing is that at the end of the algorithm, you will have lost the original `start`, so you will no longer be able to set `last_node` - unless you do that in the code which you are still to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several drawbacks of your approach.

The first one is that it is a bad idea to declare a global variable `start`.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
} head, *last_node;
```

Also if it is a singly-linked list then nodes should be inserted to the beginning of the list. So the  global pointer `last_node` is not required.

The function `reverse` deals with the local variable `start` because function parameters are local variables of functions

```
void reverse (struct Node *start)
```

The original pointer to the start node is not changed in the function because the function deals with its copy.

And the function has to check whether the passed argument is already equal to `NULL`.

There is a simple logic behind the reverse algorithm.

You should just insert already existent nodes as if you would do this within the function that pushes new nodes into list.

And the pointer to the start node (head) must be passed by reference using a pointer to it.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};

int push_front( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    struct Node *current = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        current->data = data;
        current->link = *head;
        *head = current;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->link )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

void reverse( struct Node **head )
{
    struct Node *current = *head;
    *head = NULL;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = current;
        current = current->link;
        tmp->link = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }
}    

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) push_front( &head, i );

    output( head );

    reverse( &head );

    output( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> NULL
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> NULL
```

Of course you need to append the list implementation with a function that deletes all nodes of the list when it is not anymore required.